# What is the best way to send multiple parameters to a webservice from a client, which is a scripting language?

Tags: web-services, soap, client

I would appreciate if someone can point me the recommended ways of passing multiple (say 10) parameters from client to a webservice. I have the requirements for the server side, so once I figure out the best way to pass data, I can expose the webmethod on the server side (.NET). FYI, I have a SOAP client that is implemented in Javascript. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery:

```
function AddLocation(ParentID, name, name2, code) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../server.asmx/Save",
        data: "{'ID':'0','ParentID':'" + ParentID + "','Name':'" + name + "','Name2':'" + name2 + "','Code':'" + code + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d;
            //more code here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is REST.The poster wants SOAP